# cache_clear_all() doesn't seem to work

Tags: 7, entities, caching

I have a block with a few CCK fields. In this block I have a link to an action that changes the value of the fields in that block.

The code is the following:

```
db_query("UPDATE {content_type_event} SET field_event_places_amount_value = field_event_places_amount_value - 1 WHERE nid=%d", $nid);
cache_clear_all();
```

After reloading, the old value still appear. I have to manually clear the cache to see the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a CCK field I need to use [content_clear_type_cache()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content.module/function/content_clear_type_cache/6)

Answer (score 7):

Check which cache is relevant (e.g. cache_content, cache_views_data) for this content and clear this cache explicitly. If you call cache_clear_all() without parameters you "only" clear the page and block cache. Take a look at the code of [cache_clear_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) to see the details.